# Windows client connecting to Samba 4.1.12 failing to join DC, latest Windows 11 Update?

Tags: samba4

I'm writing this here just in case someone can help me out a little bit here, since I'm kind of lost. I'm managing a domain controller through Samba version 4.1.12 (installed in a Debian 7), a little bit older version, but I'd like to know why recently I had 2 new computers that I tried to join to the DC that I couldn't join them because they said in each case the login + password for Administrator was incorrect.

The funny thing is that if I try to login / access to one of the shared folders we have, aside joining the domain, it works ok. I've just set up a laptop with the same Windows version and joined it to the domain and it also works okay, so I guess it must be some sort of Windows security update that only applied to these two new computers? They are 2 PC NUC11 with a fresh Windows 11 Pro installed.

So far, what I found is that Kerberos is complaining about the integrity check once you try to join the domain:

`Kerberos: Failed to verify authenticator checksum: Decrypt integrity check failed for checksum type rsa-md5, key type arcfour-hmac-md5`

On the other hand, when you start Samba the arcfour-hmac-md5 enctype is supported:

`Kerberos: Client supported enctypes: aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96, aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96, des3-cbc-sha1, arcfour-hmac-md5, using arcfour-hmac-md5/arcfour-hmac-md5`

Could you please anyone let me know what I might be doing wrong? Is there anything I should be paying attention to? I tried to modify my krb5.conf in order to add any new enctypes, but as far as I can see the enctype I want is already there. Should I add rsa-md5 to the list? I tried as well but it doesn't work at all.

Many, many thanks in advance for your kind help!

PS: I know I should update Samba :)

EDIT: In the end, I upgraded Samba with success, that was the only option left. You need to pay attention especially in what regards the following versions, I highly recommend you as well to perform small major upgrades before going to the latest version: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Updating_Samba

The was NO way we could get these workstations working. As far as I arrived was to get where @evs (below) referred to the Reddit link. We changed the OS cyphers for Kerberos at the Local Policy management and set-up some registry keys, but in any way we were able to access to get the system to load the GPOs (same cypher error and I could not locate where I could change it). That means, for instance, the workstations were not able to enable offline files or use folder redirection. There's a plus, there was no chance for a user to update his password. After that, I completely surrendered and updated the systems on a weekend... After reading online quite a lot, I'm afraid updates are strictly necessary in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this : https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/xoqend/samba_495_windows_11_22h2_kerberos/

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @evs! I just came across to this now... So sorry for my late reply. We checked almost everything, also setting up the cyphers to the ones described at the Reddit link. Problem was that we were not able later to access to the GPOs from the computers, so in the end the only solution was to properly upgrade Samba to the latest version. I highly recommend to do it in several steps, upgrading major versions (specially the ones described at https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Updating_Samba) so everything works flawlessly.